# Python O365 Sending Email

Tags: python, pandas, email, office365

I am trying to use the dataframe of an email rolodex to iterate an attachment and coverletter to the amount of indexes found in the dataframe. Can anyone tell me how i reference the specific column through i below for each setting?
thanks

```
body_of_email = "This is a call to arms" 
for i in email_list:
    #Send to Recipients individually from list
    m.setRecipients(i.columns[2])
    #Attachments
    m.attachments.append(excel_att)
    m.attachments.append(cover_letter)
    m.setSubject(i.columns[1] + ' I made an email script.')
    m.setBody(body_of_email)
    m.sendMessage()
```

email_list is a 3 column, number, name, email_address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `itertuples`:

```
for i in email_list.itertuples():
    #Send to Recipients individually from list
```

Use:

```
    m.setRecipients(i.email_address)
```

or

```
    m.setRecipients(i[2])
    #Attachments
    m.attachments.append(excel_att)
    m.attachments.append(cover_letter)
    m.setSubject(i.name + ' I made an email script.')
```

or

```
    m.setSubject(i[1] + ' I made an email script.')
    m.setBody(body_of_email)
    m.sendMessage()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would there be a reason the attachments duplicate each time?

Comment: Are you familiar with O365 the attachments regardless of iterrows itertuples, seems to continually be added to each additional email row.

Comment: I have no experience with O365, just Pandas. You might try, using print statements in your for loop to see what is going on.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.itertupes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas-dataframe-itertuples)